# Using word vba to format parts of table cell text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using the following code to combine text from two excel cells into a word table cell. I want to format the first part (captionStr) as bold but can't seem to figure out how to specify just that part of the range.

I tried `.Range(0,Len(captionStr)).Font.Bold=True` and `.Range.Characters(0,Len(captionStr)).Font.Bold=True` but both give me "wrong number of argument" errors. I'm using Office 2010 with MS Word 14.0 Object Reference

```
With tbl.Cell(nRow, 2).Range
    .Style = rfpDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
    captionStr = CStr(nSection) + ". " + ActiveCell.Text
    bodyStr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Text
    .Text = captionStr
    .Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    .Range.InsertAfter(bodyStr)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a Range object, rather than refer to the entire cell Range when writing the information. This gives you finer control over formatting, as you go. The formatting will always apply to the *current* content of the Range. So more like

```
Dim rngCell as Word.Range
Set rngCell = tbl.Cell(nRow, 2).Range
With rngCell
  'Go into the cell, rather than the entire cell
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  'other stuff
  .Text = captionStr & vbCr
  .Font.Bold = True
  'Move to the end of the range
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  'Doing this in a table cell moves to the next cell, so one back
  .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
  'Now the rest of the content
  .Text = bodyStr
  .Font.Bold = False
End With
```

Think of a Range like a Selection, and collapsing it like using the left-/right arrow key to "collapse" the selection to a point.