# Concatenating strings into a range with alternating font formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to concatenate a string out of some string bits and variable data with the code that looks like this:

```
HeadersRange.Text = "ID 1: " & ID1_value & "ID 2: " & ID2_value
```

The end result should look like this:

[image]
Here, the `ID 1:` and `ID 2:` bits are in bold text while the numbers are not. How do I achieve this? Neither "string" nor "integer" data types content the "font" property, so I can't make `ID 1` and `ID 2` bold before I insert them. I could concatenate the string, and then do the font formatting on the several parts of the string, but navigating the range is messy and requires me to know the amount of words in every bit up front. What is the best solution?

Comment: How to insert content with varying formatting has been asked many times before. For example: [Problem using two font formats in Word header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909884/problem-using-two-font-formats-in-word-header), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729431/using-word-vba-to-format-parts-of-table-cell-text/36730471#36730471, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285608/text-with-different-styles-in-one-paragraph-word-vba/58286269#58286269

Comment: It does, thank you.